# Fill PDF form with FDF data using PHP on shared hosting servers

Tags: php, pdf, fdf

I have an FDF file generated after filing a html form, and of course a PDF template, my question is how to merge those two files in PHP and return the PDF to the user? I can't use PDFTK because I am hosting my website on shared hosting plan of goDaddy that doesn't allow installation of third party software.

I tried passing the FDF file as parameter along with URL to the template PDF.  However, there's a limitation of 32 characters set for parameter length and my website name is quite long.

Thanks!

Comment: Considering your extremely limited server resources, you might better work with the client-side merging idea, where you send the FDF, which contains a the URI of the base PDF. When Acrobat/Reader receives an FDF, it knows how to retrieve the base PDF and to fill out the form.